# Add Class Variation Woocommerce Out Stock

Tags: wordpress, function, variables, woocommerce, product

I need to add a css style class for only "label" products that are not in stock.

Example Original Code:

```
<label class="radio-label sw-radio-variation sw-radio-variation-2" title="l" for="l_2">
```

The code I want:

```
<label class="out-stock radio-label sw-radio-variation sw-radio-variation-2" title="l" for="l_2">
```

As you see add to the CSS code out-stock

Thanks

Edit: My product-variation.php is

```html
<?php 

/*

** Product variation hook

*/

add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'sw_woocommerce_custom_variation', 10, 2 );

function sw_woocommerce_custom_variation( $html, $args ){

 $options   = $args['options'];

 $product   = $args['product'];

 $attribute = $args['attribute'];

 $name      = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute );

 $id        = $args['id'] ? $args['id'] : sanitize_title( $attribute );

 $class     = $args['class'];

 

 if ( empty( $options ) && ! empty( $product ) && ! empty( $attribute ) ) {

  $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();

  $options    = $attributes[ $attribute ];

 }

 $html = '';

 if ( ! empty( $options ) ) {

  $html .= '<div class="sw-custom-variation">'; 

  if ( $product && taxonomy_exists( $attribute ) ) {

   // Get terms if this is a taxonomy - ordered. We need the names too.

   $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), $attribute, array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );        

   foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {

    $color    = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'sw_variation_color', true );

    $active   = ( checked( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) ) ? ' selected' : '';

    $attributes = ( preg_match( '/color|colors/', $attribute, $match ) && $color != '' ) ? 'class="variation-color" style="background: '. esc_attr( $color ) .'"' : '';

    

    if ( in_array( $term->slug, $options ) ) {

     $html .= '<label class="radio-label sw-radio-variation sw-radio-variation-'. esc_attr( $key .' '. $active ) .'" title="'. esc_attr( $term->slug )  .'" for="'. esc_attr( $term->slug . '_' . $key ) . '">';

     $html .= '<input type="radio" id="'.  esc_attr( $term->slug . '_' . $key ) .'" name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '" data-attribute_name="attribute_' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute ) ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" '. checked( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) .'/>';

     $html .= '<span '. $attributes .'>'. $term->name .'</span>';

     $html .= '</label>';

    }

   }   

  }else {

   foreach ( $options as $key => $option ) {

    // This handles < 2.4.0 bw compatibility where text attributes were not sanitized.

    $checked = sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ) === $args['selected'] ? checked( $args['selected'], sanitize_title( $option ), false ) : checked( $args['selected'], $option, false );

    $active = ( $checked ) ? 'selected' : '';



    $html .= '<label class="radio-label sw-radio-variation sw-radio-variation-'. esc_attr( $key .' '. $active ) .'"  title="'. esc_attr( $option )  .'"  for="'. esc_attr( $option . '_' . $key ) . '">';

    $html .= '<input type="radio" id="'.  esc_attr( $option . '_' . $key ) .'" name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '" data-attribute_name="attribute_' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute ) ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $option ) . '" '. $checked .'/>';

    $html .= '<span>'. $option .'</span>';

    $html .= '</label>';

   }

  }

  $html .= '</div>';

 }

 return $html;

}



/*

** Action hook to color

*/



$sw_attribute_taxonomies = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();

if ( ! empty( $sw_attribute_taxonomies ) ) {

 foreach( $sw_attribute_taxonomies as $attr ){

  if( preg_match( '/color|colors/', $attr->attribute_name, $match ) ){

   add_action( 'pa_'. $attr->attribute_name .'_add_form_fields', 'sw_woocommerce_variation_fields', 200 );

   add_action( 'pa_'. $attr->attribute_name .'_edit_form_fields', 'sw_woocommerce_edit_variation_fields', 200 );

   add_action( 'created_term', 'sw_woocommerce_save_variation_fields', 10, 3 );

   add_action( 'edit_terms', 'sw_woocommerce_save_variation_fields', 10, 3 );

   

   /* Enqueue Admin js */

   add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'sw_woocommerce_variation_color_script' ); 

  }

 }

}



/*

** Create color

*/

function sw_woocommerce_variation_fields() {

 ?>

 <div class="form-field custom-picker">

  <label for="sw_variation_color"><?php _e( 'Color', 'sw_woocommerce' ); ?></label>

  <input name="sw_variation_color" id="sw_variation_color" type="text" value="" size="40" class="category-colorpicker"/>

 </div>

 <?php

}



function sw_woocommerce_edit_variation_fields( $term ) {



 $sw_variation_color = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'sw_variation_color', true );



 ?>

 <tr class="form-field custom-picker custom-picker-edit">

  <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="sw_variation_color"><?php _e( 'Color', 'sw_woocommerce' ); ?></label></th>

  <td>

   <input name="sw_variation_color" id="sw_variation_color" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $sw_variation_color ) ?>" size="40" class="category-colorpicker"/>

  </td>

 </tr>

 <?php

}



/** Save Custom Field Of Category Form */

function sw_woocommerce_save_variation_fields( $term_id, $tt_id = '', $taxonomy = '', $prev_value = '' ) {

 if ( isset( $_POST['sw_variation_color'] ) ) {   

  $term_value = esc_attr( $_POST['sw_variation_color'] );

  update_term_meta( $term_id, 'sw_variation_color', $term_value, $prev_value );

 }

}



function sw_woocommerce_variation_color_script(){

 wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' ); 

 wp_enqueue_script('category_color_picker_js', WCURL . '/js/admin/category_color_picker.js', array( 'wp-color-picker' ), false, true);

}
```

As you can see on line 60 you will find the labels
Will there be any code to add a custom CSS to these labels that create the variables?

Thanks

************** SOLUTION ***********

```
<?php
// Adiccional Class For Label Variations
function get_variation_stock_text( $product, $name, $term_slug ){
    foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation ){
        if($variation['attributes'][$name] == $term_slug ){
            $is_in_stock = $variation['is_in_stock'];
            $stock_qty   = get_post_meta($variation['variation_id'], '_stock', true);
        }
    }
    $in_stock     = ' '.__("katayainstock", "woocommerce").'';
    $out_of_stock = ' '.__("katayaoutstock", "woocommerce").'';

    return $is_in_stock == 1 ? $in_stock : $out_of_stock;
}
    /**
     * Product variation hook
     */
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'sw_woocommerce_custom_variation', 10, 2 );
    function sw_woocommerce_custom_variation( $html, $args ) {
        $options   = $args['options'];
        $product   = $args['product'];
        $attribute = $args['attribute'];
        $name      = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute );
        $id        = $args['id'] ? $args['id'] : sanitize_title( $attribute );
        $class     = $args['class'];

        if ( empty( $options ) && ! empty( $product ) && ! empty( $attribute ) ) {
            $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
            $options    = $attributes[ $attribute ];
        }

        $html = '';

        if ( ! empty( $options ) ) {

            $html .= '<div class="sw-custom-variation">';

            if ( $product && taxonomy_exists( $attribute ) ) {
                // Get terms if this is a taxonomy - ordered. We need the names too.
                $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), $attribute, array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );

                foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
                    $color      = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'sw_variation_color', true );
                    $active     = checked( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) ? ' selected' : '';
                    $attributes = ( preg_match( '/color|colors/', $attribute, $match ) && $color !== '' ) ? 'class="variation-color" style="background: ' . esc_attr( $color ) . '"' : '';

                    if ( in_array( $term->slug, $options, true ) ) {
                        $stock_text = get_variation_stock_text( $product, $name, $term->slug );
                        $html .= '<label class="' . $stock_text . ' radio-label sw-radio-variation sw-radio-variation-' . esc_attr( $key . ' ' . $active ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" for="' . esc_attr( $term->slug . '_' . $key ) . '">';
                        $html .= '<input type="radio" id="' . esc_attr( $term->slug . '_' . $key ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '" data-attribute_name="attribute_' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute ) ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . checked( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) . '/>';
                        $html .= '<span ' . $attributes . '>' . $term->name . '</span>';
                        $html .= '</label>';
                    }
                }
            } else {
                foreach ( $options as $key => $option ) {
                    // This handles < 2.4.0 bw compatibility where text attributes were not sanitized.
                    $checked = sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ) === $args['selected'] ? checked( $args['selected'], sanitize_title( $option ), false ) : checked( $args['selected'], $option, false );
                    $active  = ( $checked ) ? 'selected' : '';
                    $html    .= '<label class="radio-label sw-radio-variation sw-radio-variation-' . esc_attr( $key . ' ' . $active ) . '"  title="' . esc_attr( $option ) . '"  for="' . esc_attr( $option . '_' . $key ) . '">';
                    $html    .= '<input type="radio" id="' . esc_attr( $option . '_' . $key ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '" data-attribute_name="attribute_' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute ) ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $option ) . '" ' . $checked . '/>';
                    $html    .= '<span>' . $option . '</span>';
                    $html    .= '</label>';
                }
            }

            $html .= '</div>';
        }

        return $html;
    }

    /**
     * Action hook color
     */
    $sw_attribute_taxonomies = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();
    if ( ! empty( $sw_attribute_taxonomies ) ) {
        foreach ( $sw_attribute_taxonomies as $attr ) {
            if ( preg_match( '/color|colors/', $attr->attribute_name, $match ) ) {
                add_action( 'pa_' . $attr->attribute_name . '_add_form_fields', 'sw_woocommerce_variation_fields', 200 );
                add_action( 'pa_' . $attr->attribute_name . '_edit_form_fields', 'sw_woocommerce_edit_variation_fields', 200 );
                add_action( 'created_term', 'sw_woocommerce_save_variation_fields', 10, 3 );
                add_action( 'edit_terms', 'sw_woocommerce_save_variation_fields', 10, 3 );
                add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'sw_woocommerce_variation_color_script' );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create color
     */
    function sw_woocommerce_variation_fields() { ?>

        <div class="form-field custom-picker">
            <label for="sw_variation_color"><?php _e( 'Color', 'sw_woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <input name="sw_variation_color" id="sw_variation_color" type="text" value="" size="40"
                   class="category-colorpicker"/>
        </div>

        <?php
    }

    /**
     * @param $term
     */
    function sw_woocommerce_edit_variation_fields( $term ) {
        $sw_variation_color = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'sw_variation_color', true ); ?>

        <tr class="form-field custom-picker custom-picker-edit">
            <th scope="row" valign="top"><label
                        for="sw_variation_color"><?php _e( 'Color', 'sw_woocommerce' ); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <input name="sw_variation_color" id="sw_variation_color" type="text"
                       value="<?php echo esc_attr( $sw_variation_color ) ?>" size="40" class="category-colorpicker"/>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Save custom field of category form
     *
     * @param $term_id
     * @param string $tt_id
     * @param string $taxonomy
     * @param string $prev_value
     */
    function sw_woocommerce_save_variation_fields( $term_id, $tt_id = '', $taxonomy = '', $prev_value = '' ) {
        if ( isset( $_POST['sw_variation_color'] ) ) {
            $term_value = esc_attr( $_POST['sw_variation_color'] );
            update_term_meta( $term_id, 'sw_variation_color', $term_value, $prev_value );
        }
    }

    function sw_woocommerce_variation_color_script() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'category_color_picker_js', WCURL . '/js/admin/category_color_picker.js', array( 'wp-color-picker' ), false, true );
    }
```

Comment: Way to little data to give an effective answer.

Can you post the full HTML for the section where your radio buttons are?

Comment: oik edit men thanks!

Comment: Do you have a live link?

Comment: Yes bro, https://nikostore.net/store/E304/camisa-deluxe-blanca
Size L is sold out
A cache plugin is currently activated but to perform the tests I deactivate it.

Comment: plz help will there be any functional code?

Comment: I found the solution. Edit post thanks my bro!

Comment: Excellent. Will look over it tonight.